# Android - вылетает при запуске приложения на более ранней версии ОС

Tags: android, java

Запускаю приложение на `4.0.4`, `4.1.2`, `4.4.2` - всё работает отлично. Но при запуске на `2.3.6` приложение крашится, вот лог:

```
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{xxx.yyy/xxx.yyy.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx.yyy.MainActivity in loader         dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/xxx.yyy-1.apk]
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx.yyy.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/xxx.yyy-1.apk]
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
03-01 20:38:27.579 E/AndroidRuntime(2447):  ... 11 more
```

Все компоненты приложения совместимы с 2.3.6, в манифесте прописано `minSdkVersion="8"`. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Хм, `MainActivity` точно в манифесте объявлено?

Comment: Да. Всё прописано.

Comment: @SuperCreeper - на `stackoverflow` пишут, что такая ошибка ещё возникает когда активити объявлена `abstract`.

Comment: @ua6xh, если бы класс был бы абстрактным, то приложение вылетало на всех андроидах.

Comment: Может линкуется что из библиотек не то?

Comment: Было подозрение насчёт этого, так как в приложении я впервые использовал NavigationDrawer.

Comment: Рядом с android-support-v4 в java build path галочку поставь и в самый верх его подними.

Comment: MainActivity наследует какой класс ? :) MainActivity extends что ?

Answer (score 1):

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Ошибка явно говорит, что не может найти класс. Тут скорее всего обычная несовместимость с ранними версиями

Answer (score 0):

Может происходит Переполнение памяти на более ранних девайсах? У меня такое было из-за большой вложенности в layout'a

Comment: Если было бы переполнение памяти, то выкидывало бы OutOfMemoryException, a у меня совсем другое.